# How to create two separate jars with wsdl2java?

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml, wsdl2java

I’m very new to maven. I’m using wsdl2java to get the Java files and then create the jar file I need. The problem is that my urls come from different sources and eventually I need to have 4 different jar files.

So far, I tried to create the first two jar files and deal with the next two later... So I created two different "execution" blocks in the "build" block; each "execution" block downloads each own wsdl files, so far so good.  The following plugin:

org.codehaus.mojo
axistools-maven-plugin

Works this way: it first compiles all the generated Java files and then generates the jar file out of all the files, meaning it creates only one jar file.

Is there anyway, I ask wsdl2java to compile and then create the jar files right after each "execution" block? That I can get two different jar file each relating only to the wsdl files I downloaded in that "execution" block?

Following is pom.xml.  At this point the generated jar file consists of the Java files generated from: file1, file2, file3, file4 and file5.

Where I want one jar from: file1, file2 and file3 and the other from: file4 and file5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<build>
<plugins>    
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>        
    <dependencies>          
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>prod</id>          
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>    

      <urls>
        <url>https://file1.svc?wsdl</url>
        <url>https://file2.svc?wsdl</url>
        <url>https://file3.svc?wsdl</url>                        
      </urls>

      <allElements>true</allElements>
      <wrapArrays>false</wrapArrays>
      <testCases>false</testCases>
      <serverSide>false</serverSide>
      <typeMappingVersion>1.2</typeMappingVersion>                      
    </configuration>
      </execution>

      <execution>
      <id>sandbox</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/wsdl</sourceDirectory>

    <useEmitter>true</useEmitter>        
<wsdlFiles>
    <wsdlFile>file4.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>file5.wsdl</wsdlFile>
</wsdlFiles>    

      <allElements>true</allElements>
      <wrapArrays>false</wrapArrays>
      <testCases>false</testCases>
      <serverSide>false</serverSide>
      <typeMappingVersion>1.2</typeMappingVersion>                             
    </configuration>
      </execution>          
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Since its too long for comment, I had to edit my original post...

Thanks for the reply. I did try your solution. As you are aware, the "axistools-maven-plugin" has the "maven-compiler-plugin" and the "maven-jar-plugin" built in. It first downloads all wsdl files, from the specified urls. It creates different output directories; however, in the compile phase, it tries to compile all the Java files in all output directories at once; since there are some Java files which are common bet. these wsdl files, it gives the "duplicate class" error at compile time.

We can define our own custom "maven-compiler-plugin" and "maven-jar-plugin" blocks and add the "include" or "exclude" blocks to let maven know what files to compile and how to create the jar files, but since "axistools-maven-plugin" runs its own "maven-compiler-plugin" first, it tries to compile all the Java files first and still gives  "duplicate class" error **before** it looks at our "maven-compiler-plugin" and "maven-jar-plugin" blocks.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: define `<outputDirectory>` for each of your axistools plugin executions, e.g. "classesProd" and "classesSandbox".

Then use multiple executions of the `maven-jar-plugin` to build jars from these files.  Each jar plugin execution would specify a `<classesDirectory>` corresponding to the `<outputDirectory>` of the axistools executions.  You would want to define the `<classifier>` or change the `<outputDirectory>` for the jar executions so the second jar doesn't overwrite the first.

Comment: Another comment... before I can have different "execution" blocks for the maven-jar-plugin, I need to let wsdl2java know where to compile the classes; meaning I have to have different "execution" blocks for maven-compiler-plugin. But the problem is that I don't know how to define the dir for compiled classes except for default target/classes and target/test-classes? Remember that I need to create 4 different jars so I need to have four "execution" blocks for maven-compiler-plugin and four "execution" blocks for maven-jar-plugin. But then how to have the custom target directories for classes?

Comment: I am wondering if this would work better as 4 separate projects in a multi module build.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the creation of the duplicate java classes by adding nsExcludes to the configuration section of the wsdl2java.

```
<goals>
<goal>wsdl2java</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<nsExcludes>
  <nsExclude>http://lang.java</nsExclude>
  <nsExclude>http://rmi.java</nsExclude>
</nsExcludes>
...
```